# Jquery shows nothing with master details

Tags: jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller, master-detail

I´m using VS 2013 to create a master-detail view, but when I click on the list, Jquery should show me the PK of the registry and the dialog box comes up but it shows no pk.

```
    @model IEnumerable<MasterDetailsMVC4.Models.Orders>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@section styles{
    <style>
        .highlight {
            background-color: rgb(230,244,224);
        }
    </style>
    }

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#master tbody tr").click(function () {
                $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');                
                var Id = this.cells[0].textContext;
                alert(Id);
            });
        });
    </script>
    }
    <h1>Master details using asp.net mvc 4</h1>
<br\></br\>
<h2>Orders</h2>

<table class="table " id="master">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CustomerID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RequiredDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShippedDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipVia)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Freight)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipAddress)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipCity)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipRegion)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipPostalCode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipCountry)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequiredDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShippedDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShipVia)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Freight)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShipName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShipAddress)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShipCity)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShipRegion)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShipPostalCode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShipCountry)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }

</table>


<h2>Orders Details</h2>

<table class="table " id="details">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CustomerID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RequiredDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShippedDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipVia)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Freight)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipAddress)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipCity)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipRegion)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipPostalCode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipCountry)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td colspan="13">
            <p>Seleccione una orden</p>
        </td>


    </tr>


</table>
```

This is the link of the entire project
[Master detail project](http://mega.nz/#F!Wn4g1Qha!L1-0bkz78DtU-q1bqPih3g)

The idea is using the PK of one registry to fill the part on the bottom

Comment: The idea of the 'mostly code' message is to have you think about posting less code, not adding nonsense text to make up the ratio - see [mcve]

Comment: Are you looking for this? var Id = this.cells[0].innerHTML;

Comment: I´ve tried that but it doesn´t work @Rosebud